# How do you create an MS Access table in C# programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, ms-access

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable (" +
                "[Count] INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ," +
                "[TimeAndDate] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ," +
                "[SerialNumber] VARCHAR( 14 ) NOT NULL ," +
                "[Result] BOOL NOT NULL ," +
                "UNIQUE ([TimeAndDate]))";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Code above flags syntax error exception, can you help me correct the query string? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest pasting the resulting query text into an Access query; it will tell you where the error is.

On my Access XP, pasting the resulting SQL gave a syntax error on AUTO_INCREMENT; it should be AUTOINCREMENT (see [Access 2007 SQL data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177899.aspx)) and be specified as a data type, not a constraint.
BOOL also gave an error => use BIT

Result which worked:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
               [Count] AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
               [TimeAndDate] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
               [SerialNumber] VARCHAR( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
               [Result] BIT NOT NULL ,
               UNIQUE ([TimeAndDate]));
```

Comment: How can you do that in Access? Where did you paste the SQL statement?

Comment: Create a new query; View menu shows Design, Datasheet and SQL (or something of the kind). Choose SQL. Alternatively, you could paste it in a suitable command in the VBA/code editor (Alt-F11) immediate window (Ctrl-G), e.g. currentdb.Execute("bla") (where bla is the sql statement). For newer versions of access you might need to set a reference to the dao library though...

Answer (score 2):

You need an ending parenthesis `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just after MyTable you use an open bracket "(", that you do not close.

To create tables in Access, I normally use [ADOX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677200%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), this prevents this kind of syntax errors.