# How can I run a make table query against an Access DB using ADO?

Tags: ms-access, ado

I've got a legacy program, and I'm working with Access 97. I want to use ADO to make new table that has the exact same structure as another table.

- I tried using this : [Create new table from a query on another table in ado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403729/create-new-table-from-a-query-on-another-table-using-ado)
- And this: [How do you create a MS table in C# programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781323/how-do-you-create-an-ms-access-table-in-c-sharp-programmatically)

This is what I'm getting:

```
 Select * FROM [TempMergeTable] INTO [TempMergeTableFix]
 Syntax error in FROM clause
```

TempMergeTableFix doesn't exist already. Will this not work with Access 97?

What's going on and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it was a syntax error after all. It really should have been:

```
SELECT * INTO newtable FROM source;
```